# What is the fastest way to redirect a page to another url?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to redirect my blogger website to a external url
There is tow code to do that

1. Using meta tag
   `<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url='https://google.com'`
2. Javascript
   `<script>window.location.href = "https://google.com";</script>`

I want to know what is the fastest way to redirect and what is the most supported method by browsers?

Comment: respond with the appropriate status code and the `Location` header from your server directly

Comment: You mention blogger... if that means that you can't control the HTTP headers, then go with option #1

Comment: @Josiah keller   I can use the first and second methods, but I want to know which method is more supported by browsers

Comment: @farhat I suggest the first because it doesn't require JS. I would assume it's probably faster too since it doesn't spin up the JS parser.

Answer (score 0):

Having your site redirect your users would determine on how you want to accomplish this.

If you want it to auto load after a few seconds.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5"; url="https://www.google.com"/>
```

The "content=5" allows you to set the time frame (in seconds) on how fast/slow you want your website to redirect your users.

Otherwise, if you want them to click on a button to activate your redirect,

```
<button type="button" href="https://www.google.com">Refresh</button>
```

This will allow your users to click on the button and your website is replaced with the new on. If you want your website to stay opened up, and want the new website in a new tab, use this code;

```
<button type="button" href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Refresh</button>
```